# firebase.auth() using $scope after login

Tags: angularjs, facebook, firebase, angularjs-scope, firebase-authentication

I use a simples ng-model to show login/content using angularjs, look my facebookAuthProvider:

```
   $scope.enterFacebook = function() {
       var auth = firebase.auth();
       var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
     auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
     console.log('logged.');
     $scope.loggedSystem = true;
     $scope.loginScreen = false;
         }).catch(function(error) {
           var errorCode = error.code;
           var errorMessage = error.message;
           console.log(errorCode+'=>'+errorMessage);
         });
                                     }
```

My problem:

Facebook auth work fine, but $scope.loggedSystem and $scope.loginScreen not. Its only works when I click two times (ng-click='enterFacebook()')

How I can make it work with one click?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just use:

> $scope.$apply();